# How can I get tweets more than a year

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get twitters timelime using tweepy, but I can't get old tweets that are more than a year ago.

My Python script is shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import tweepy
import json

CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = api.get_user(screen_name='twitter_acount')
for tw in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, user_id=user.id, count=15000).items():
    json_str = json.dumps(tw._json)
    print json_str
    print '\n'
```

I executed this script for getting tweets of a user who tweeted more than 15000, but I only got about 3113 tweets and the date of the oldest tweet I got is 22 Nov 2015, i.e., a year ago.

Comment: Once upon a time I have tried this. But I think you cant get more than one year old tweets. If you want you have to go to twitter in commercial way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter Search API is limited to 7 days of history, and the timeline APIs are limited on the number of Tweets that can be retrieved. Actually you should [only be able to fetch 3200 Tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) so I'm not sure how you're seeing 9800.

If you need historic data, then [Twitter's Gnip products](http://gnip.com) offer comprehensive coverage. These are commercial APIs.

Comment: You're correct. I made mistake. I counted null rows. 3113 tweets I got is correct.