# How to query twitter API with respect to time using Tweepy?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have access to Twitter's API, and I'm using the Tweepy module to query tweets. However, I can't figure out how to search tweets in a specific time slot, like march 1st - july 20th.

Comment: Hi Colton. Could you share some of the code you've written - even if it doesn't work. That will help us figure out this answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get tweets more than a year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756263/how-can-i-get-tweets-more-than-a-year)

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API only allows you to query back in time for 7 days, see the API documentation. That is, unless you pay for that extra access.